# Writing a PHP file to another file, in another directory, with different values dependant on variables

Tags: php, cron

I'm fairly new to PHP, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to create something to write a PHP file to another file in another directory. The idea being that all the generated directories have to include a file which is run via cron, however I can't simply just copy the file because part of the file is dependant on a variable that exists when the directory gets created, but isn't always going to be there.

It would be the same scenario as writing the following to a file (obviously this is an example):

```
<?php
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHEN memberID='$groupID'");
?>
```

How would I get the variable `$groupID` from the file carrying out the `fopen('','w')` function which is writing the new PHP file? Can anyone give an example of writing the above to a file?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've accepted the answer to the original question, however the answer from @MichaelBerkowski is an efficient alternative to consider.

Comment: Can you explain better what kinds of actions the cron script would be undertaking? What is in those directories besides the PHP ? Writing PHP files to be executed really seems like the wrong solution to almost any problem. There may be a much simpler way of handling this that has been overlooked.

Comment: It's a file to notify people of new files added to that directory in the last X hours

Comment: Notify what people? Do the people vary by the directory? Are people tied to directories in your database?

Comment: There are X number of people who can upload to a directory, and all these people only belong to one directory. They're tied to the directories, and I just want to notify them daily with what has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood what you want to do, but in case I did:

```
<?php
$groupId = 343; // Define your Id here
$string = "<?php
    $test = mysql_query(\"SELECT * FROM table WHEN memberID='".$groupId."'\");?>";
$file = fopen("yournewfile.php","w");
fwrite($file,$string);
fclose($file);
?>
```

This will write the content you provided (the PHP file) into the file "yournewfile.php"

Comment: This is kinda what I want, except that I want `$groupID` to be replaced with the value of `$groupID` as defined in that file. Say your example had a variable `$groupID` at the start which was defined differently each time the file ran, how do I make it put that value into the string?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives I updated my answer to reflect what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose an alternate solution. Rather than generate PHP files which get executed by cron in each directory, perhaps the better solution is to create *one* PHP script which is run by cron and descends into each of your dynamic directories and performs the necessary task there.

If all of your directories are in one place or at one level, then it may be as simple as iterating with a `glob('dirs/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)` to locate them.  If the directory structure is more complex, you may need to descend recursively.

However, if your directory membership is associated in your database, it really just becomes a matter of selecting all the directories from the database with their associated members, and checking the `filectime()` of files contained therein to do your notifications.